# Pass variable to html with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I made a listing of files that exist in a particular folder, I would like that after listing, it would be possible to access this variable in HTML.

**Server.js**

```
var http = require('http');    
var arquivo = require('fs');
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){      
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});     
    arquivo.readFile(__dirname+'/pagina.html', 
        function(err, html){             
        if (err) {
            response.write("Arquivo não encontrado!");                   
            response.end();
        } else{
            response.write(html);   
            var fs = require('fs');
            var files = fs.readdirSync(__dirname+'/list/'); //LIST FOLDER           
            response.end();

        }      
    });
});
server.listen(3000, function(){       
    console.log('Servidor está rodando!');     
});
```

**pagina.html**

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(files); //Name of var list
</script>
</hmtL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replacing a raw string with a variable has several clean solutions. I would recommend any of the following:

- [handlebars](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js)
- [ejs](http://ejs.co/)
- [hogan](http://twitter.github.io/hogan.js/)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this.

1. separate your call into another endpoint on your server and make a request on the client (recommended since you will need this later probably)
2. use regex to change your html file (fun experiment)

imagine your html file looks like this; notice the double brackets.

```
"<html><body><script> var files = {{myvars}} </script></body></html>"
```

and you have a list of files in an array

```
var yourFiles = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3']
```

you can then use regex to fill in the variables in the original html string

```
var newHTML = html.replace('/\{\{myvars\}\}/', JSON.stringify(yourFiles))
response.write(newHTML);
response.end();
```

the final html sent will look like this

```
"<html><body><script> var files = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3'] </script></body></html>"
```